# How to know if an API returns a response with status code 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

Basically I am starting with Jest and I want to know with this tool if an API returns a response with status code 200. I have searched many ways to do it on the internet but none of them worked for me and I kept getting errors.

Could someone give me a hand on that?

For example, make a Rick & Morty API call with either Axios or Fetch and see if it returns a 200 status code:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character

I tried something like this:

**File "mock.js"**

```
import axios from "axios";


const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
        let res = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
    }

    catch(error) {
      console.log('Error! D:')
    }
}


export default getMovies;
```

**File "mock.test.js"**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import getMovies from './mock.js';


jest.mock('getMovies');

test('should return a 200 status code', () => {
    expect(getMovies.status).toBe(200)
})
```

**And it shows me the following:**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68481988/jest-mock-cannot-find-module).

The `moduleName` parameter in `jest.mock()` is a path.

See the [official docs here](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options).

**File "mock.test.js"**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import getMovies from './mock.js';


jest.mock('./mock.js');

test('should return a 200 status code', async () => {
    const res = await getMovies()
    expect(res.status).toBe(200)
})
```

You also are not returning the response from the Axios get call.

**File "mock.js"**

```
import axios from "axios";


const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
        let res = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character')
        return res
    }

    catch(error) {
      console.log('Error! D:')
      return error.response
    }
}


export default getMovies;
```

The preferred method for testing endpoints is by mocking them, this way you won't need to make a network call. The reasons why and the several approaches are [covered in this article](https://dev.to/zaklaughton/the-only-3-steps-you-need-to-mock-an-api-call-in-jest-39mb).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time @stephenlcurtis, but it stills saying me that there is an error.
<br>
`Expected: 200
    Received: undefined

      6 |
      7 | test('should return a 200 status code', () => {
    > 8 |     expect(getMovies.status).toBe(200)
        |                              ^
      9 | })

      at Object.<anonymous> (mock.test.js:8:30)`

Comment: I edited my response to address this issue. The two code edits pointed out separate issues and didn't work in tandem, apologies.

Comment: Dont worry :) also i tried again, but stills with an error, something about "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')", im gonna update my own answer with a new image.

Comment: I am still a little unclear why you're trying to test a live endpoint, as opposed to mocking it. I hope you have a chance to read the article I shared. Testing live endpoint responses follows a different approach that unit tests within a client application.

Comment: Basically I want to know when my aplication receves a correct answer (a 200 status code) from the API to start to work normally.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the way @stephenlcurtis said, but it stills saying me that there is an error:

[image: Second result (part 1)]


[image: Second result (part 2)]

**UPDATE:**

[image: Third result]

Comment: I edited my response to address this issue. The two code edits pointed out separate issues and didn't work in tandem, apologies.

Comment: @stephenlcurtis Dont worry :) also i tried again, but stills with an error, something about `"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')"`, im gonna update my own answer with a new image.